# How to change src value in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In a UIWebview I want to change

```
<iframe src=“//player.vimeo.com/video/164231311?autoplay=1” width=“700" height=“394” frameborder=“0" webkitallowfullscreen=“” mozallowfullscreen=“” allowfullscreen=“”></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe src=“//player.vimeo.com/video/164231311" width=“700” height=“394" frameborder=“0” webkitallowfullscreen=“” mozallowfullscreen=“” allowfullscreen=“”></iframe>
```

since I want the user to be presented with a play button instead of a pause button since autoplay is not allowed on iOS. It'll be more natural for the user to see a play button directly instead of the pause button as in the image below.

How do I do that in a simple way? I’ve tried some stuff like

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:“document.getElementsByTagName(…)
```

without success so far.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made rough demo code to solve your issue. Put your logic with that and it will solve your issue. 
It was tested and had seems working perfectly.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "file:///Users/user/Downloads/index.html")!))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        // get your current iframe src value
        let iframeSrcValue:String = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src")!

        // Here is your current value with AutoPlay
        print(iframeSrcValue)

        //Create new URL without Auto Play
        let modifiedSrcValue = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/td8pYyuCIIs"

        // Apply it to webview
        let evaluate: String = "document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src='\(modifiedSrcValue)';"
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: evaluate)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @arunjos007! I used your suggestion with some modification and worked out great!